# why does jquery dialog() auto height, width fail?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-dialog

I am using some jquery pop up dialogure

```
 var div = $('#mditem_temp');
 var dlg = $(div).html(data).dialog({
                        height: 'auto',
                        width: 'auto',
                        modal: true,
                        show: "drop",
                        hide: "fold",
                        position: "top",
                        autoResize:true,
                        close: function (event, ui) {
                            $("#mditem_temp").dialog('close');
                        },
                        buttons: {
                            'Add': function (d) {
                                pqr();

                                $(this).dialog('close');
                                $("#mditem_temp").dialog('close');

                            }
                        }
                    }).dialog('open');
```

and the data that is to write in it is a partial view, but the pop up do not adjust height width with the data. What may be the reason?

Comment: What does the data look like? Is it a fixed with element (img, iframe)?

Answer (score 1):

This would generally be caused by a fixed height/width or display issue in your data variable.  Inspect the rendered partial in Firebug or a similar tool and see if it's rendering outside the dialog's contained area.  If it's not then it's the size of your data html that is causing the issue.

Another option, of course, would be to dynamically set the dialog's height on each opening:

```
$(div).html(data).dialog({
  ...
  open: function(){
    var height = [calculate height with JS];
    $(this).height(height);
  }
});
```